# What post size should I use for a 20'x24' deck

Tags: decking

My deck is 20' by 24'.  Should we use 6x6 posts or 4x4 posts?  Which will look better on such a large deck?

Comment: Depends on how many posts you are going to use, the footers, local codes, and the load they are going to support. As for what looks better, it will depend on the style of deck, materials used, the balance with the house, and personal subjective opinion. (In other words, this isn't really an answerable question with the lack of details)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even consider using a 4x4 post on a deck that big unless it was more of a patio.  First most code requires 6x6 or greater for decks.  Then you could have some huge warping issues with 4x4s - if you used them and they are more than a couple of feet you better strap then.  Also you can notch the 6x6s for rails and stuff - you won't be able to nothing a 4x4 without taking out its whole top.  This doesn't even get into strength comparisons.